# Is it possible to generate a dependency graph of files included via RequireJS?

Tags: magento2, javascript, requirejs

In Magento 2 lots of JavaScript files are loaded via RequireJS.

Those files, themselves, can also `require` more JavaScript files, and so on.

This can make it difficult to determine where a specific .js file actually comes from.

Is there a way we can view a hierarchical-style depdency tree of RequireJS calls, to see which file called `require` on the file currently being loaded?